# SAXParser can't find tag

Tags: saxparser

I'm trying to parse a xml file with a SAXParser

There's a Genres Tag in my xml-file

```
<genres>
    <com.omertron.themoviedbapi.model.Genre>
        <id>28</id>
        <name>Action</name>
    </com.omertron.themoviedbapi.model.Genre>
    <com.omertron.themoviedbapi.model.Genre>
        <id>53</id>
        <name>Thriller</name>
    </com.omertron.themoviedbapi.model.Genre>
    <com.omertron.themoviedbapi.model.Genre>
        <id>10769</id>
        <name>Foreign</name>
    </com.omertron.themoviedbapi.model.Genre>
</genres>
```

and I try to parse it with this code:

```
if(localName.equals("genres")) {
        movie.setGenres(new ArrayList<Genre>());
    }
    if(localName.equals("com.omertron.themoviedbapi.model.Genre")) {
        System.out.println("True");
        movie.getGenres().add(new Genre());
    } 
    if(localName.equals("name")) {
        movie.getGenres().get(movie.getGenres().size()).setGenre(currentValue);
    }
```

I don't need the id of the genre so I go over it.

the saxparser now can find the "genres" tag but the condition:

```
if(localName.equals("com.omertron.themoviedbapi.model.Genre"))
```

is never true so I can't parse it.

Why isn't this true? It should be the correct tagname.

Comment: Did you try printing the tag name if it does not match any of your expectations?

Comment: yeah i did. maybe this is happening when the genres tag is without entries. is it possible to put the last two conditions into the first condition after movie.setGenres(new ArrayList<Genre>()); ?